# How to take min and max values with pandas dates out of range (pre-1700)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with old dates in the `dates` column, with a list of dates in each row. I would like to take their duration for each row but I can't because they are pre-1600.

```
data['Duration'] = (
    # explode lists into usable Series and convert to Datetime
    pd.to_datetime(aaa['dates'].explode())
        .groupby(level=0).agg(['min', 'max'])  # Get min and max per group
        .diff(axis=1)
        # Diff across rows
        .iloc[:, -1]  # Get the resulting difference
)
```

So far this throws an error, but I still have to take the duration. What to do?

Comment: Providing the error would help others to resolve your issue.

Comment: pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1643-06-20 00:00:00

Comment: did you check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035615/pandas-not-recognising-older-dates-pre-1600